# How to find number of rows when grouped

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to retrieve the number of rows grouped with condition for controlling the number of rows for display. With primary key there is no problem I get the count(*) but when in case of other fields such as date, nom where there is much rows with the same name and date I found a primitive way to find the number of rows wich will be displayed as below:

```
    public static int GetRapportPgeNbr(string Qry, int param)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int result = 0;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Qry,conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                 MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 try
                 {
                     while (reader.Read())
                     {
                         result = result + Convert.ToInt16(reader["rows"]);
                         ++counter;
                     }
                 }
                 catch(MySqlException e)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show(e.Number.ToString() + " -> " + e.Message.ToString());
                     return result;
                 }
             }
        }
        if (param == 1)
            return counter;
        else 
            return result;
    }
```

The param variable guides me either I get the sum of rows (sometimes there is 2 or more tables with union) or counter.

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a223dd/1)

In this exemple I have 5 rows but I need only 4 rows so I take the result of the counter.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Marking an answer as accepted is how we indicate questions as resolved. There is no need to put RESOLVED in the title.

Comment: I did not know this facility I will remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT nom)` and remove the `GROUP BY` to get the total count:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nom) AS rows 
FROM ProdMacaron
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a223dd/4)

This will give you 4 not 5.

You can, however, add the `GROUP BY nom`, but this is useless with `COUNT(DISTINCT nom)` this [will give you ones](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a223dd/3) for any values in your table.

Comment: Will try and come back